# Are there (developer) tools to remove files from Android "Rom" cache, if the smartphone doesn't start properly?

Tags: adb, fastboot, boot, cache, motorola-moto-g5

(I have also asked on stackoverflow, as I assume the use of developer tools is neccessary, but I would be very glad to get any working help on here also.

The Google Photo App filled up the 16 GByte "Rom" of my Motorola G5: Google memory overview showed around 6.5 GByte of "Google Photo" data, whereas real (not deleted) photos and videos were only 4 GByte and I had moved those 4Gbyte to the SD card. To be on the save side before hitting "delete" of the 6.5 GByte, I removed the SD card beforehand. But now, when trying to restart, Android is stuck in the booting/start sequence. (I still can enter the pin, then the normal boot/start screen appears, but that only disappears shortly each 5 to 10 seconds. Stuck there.)

**Question: Could I access in any way the "Rom" of the smartphone, so I could remove all or part of the 6.5 GByte occupied by "Google Photo", using for example adb?**

I have Android 8.1 on the G5 and Win 10 on my computer.

Comment: microSD card is readable in windows card reader?

Comment: The smartphone doesn't start, regardless which SD card is in it, or if there is none at all.

Comment: I ask reformulated: microSD card is formatted as adoptable-storage (bonded to internal storage) and you tried re-insert the same already, but doesn't start?

Comment: Yes. (And usually it started with or without SD card, formatted or not formatted.) Though I'm not sure anymore, if I tried another SD card beside the original. Should I try with another SD card??

Comment: then you are left with OEM backup tools and factory reset. be aware if microSD card is formatted as adoptable-storage, you will lose this content too

Comment: which backup tools?

Comment: And what should I do to prevent being asked for the google account password after a factory reset? I can't exclude, that I sadly have associated some randomly generated google-account with some more or less random password. I read, I can't use the smartphone anymore else.??

Comment: Could the recover logs of the recovery menu be of any help? Could I apply a helping update from SD card? (via the recovery menu's "Apply update from SD card")

Comment: maybe you can figure out google account from logs

Comment: How should there the password be in? Let's hope not.

Comment: once you remember the google account you can try https://www.google.com/accounts/ForgotPasswd

Comment: it is possible to dump (encrypted) userdata partition with QSaharaServer by using the read tag with `readbackverify="false"` (experts only). for FBE you could then just delete some files. sadly your device uses FDE. the only (unrealistic) chance is to downgrade bootloader in order to make bootchain vulnerable, disable avb and flash twrp (which decryptes userdata). this will take several days for research. you can start with figuring out how to boot in EDL mode via test point

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220648

Comment: https://www.motorola.com/us/lenovo-motorola-smart-assistant